# Lock txt files using GIT LFS?

Tags: git

Is it possible to lock "txt" files using GIT LFS , if not is there any alternative to lock files in git to prevent other users from using it (similar to Checkout in ClearCase)

Comment: see [Where does my git question go?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6311/where-does-my-git-question-go)

Answer (score 1):

I've never heard of any way to lock a file (could be wrong), but I think that changing the workflow a bit could help.

Have contributors submit a Pull Request. One person can be assigned to review Pull Requests, and simply reject them if they modified any files that you don't want changed.

Comment: Or, just ask your *trusted* contributors to refrain from editing txt files.  You shouldn't  have to change your entire workflow just to protect a few txt files.

Comment: yeaaah but that's a very long process since too many people are working on the same project . the  idea here  is when i want to make some changes on a file i need to lock it for me ( no one could modify it) after finishing commit and unlock the file.

Answer (score 0):

Right in the git lfs documentation: https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/wiki/File-Locking

> Git LFS v2.0.0 includes an early release of File Locking. File Locking lets developers lock files they are updating to prevent other users from updating them at the same time.
>
> ...
>
> When you are ready to edit files, run the lock command:
>
> ```
> $ git lfs lock images/foo.jpg
> Locked images/foo.jpg
> ```
>
> This registers the file as locked in your name on the server. You can view this with the locks command.
>
> ```
> $ git lfs locks
> images/bar.jpg  jane   ID:123
> images/foo.jpg  alice  ID:456
> ```
>
> The file will also be ready for you to edit and push locally. If at any time you decide you don't need the lock, you can remove it by passing the path or ID to the unlock command.
>
> ```
> $ git lfs unlock images/foo.jpg
> $ git lfs unlock --id=456
> ```
>
> You can also unlock someone else's file with the --force flag:
>
> ```
> $ git lfs unlock images/foo.jpg --force
> ```